# Sobolev spaces, density

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces

¿How can I prove, using a sequence of mollifiers,  that the set $C^{\infty}_{c}(I)$ (also known as $\mathcal{D}(I)$)  is dense in $W^{1,p}_{0}(I)$?

Also I want to know that if $u\in W^{1,p}(I)\cap C_{c}(I)$ then $u\in W^{1,p}_{0} (I)$

Here $I\subset\mathbb{R}$ a open interval.

¿Could help me by computing an unconventional example?

Comment: What is your definition of $W_0^{1,p}(I)$? I ask, because sometimes it is defined as the closure of $\mathcal{D}(I)$ w.r.t. the Sobolev norm.

Comment: $W^{1,p}_{0}(I)$ is the clousure of $C^{1}_{c}(I)$ in the space $W^{1,p}(I)$  w.r.t the Sobolev norm. $\vert\vert u\vert\vert_{L^{p}}+ \vert\vert u^{\prime}\vert\vert_{L^{p}} $

Comment: In this case, I try to demonstrate, under this new definition, that the set of test functions is dense in $W^{1.p}_{0}(I)$. I try to demonstrate your definition.